# Android Button width design

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I am new to Android. I am designing a  app and caught with this. 
I have 3 buttons one below the other..  All buttons should be of equal width.. Text content can change dynamically..   Based on the highest width of text in any button, other buttons must take the same width.

Can someone tell me hw to achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Either a `RelativeLayout` where the `Button`s sides are relative to each other, or find the width in java code and apply it to each button.

Comment: instead u can make use of layout_weight for achieving your purpose

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:text="abc"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:text="defdfsfafsasf"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

    <Button
        android:text="ghi"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The `LinearLayout' tries to minimize it's size without warping it's views, so the Button's minimum width is used (which is dependent on text length).
Then, each Button takes the width of the linear layout, which is the width of the largest text view.

Comment: Just a note, if you're developing in API 8+, use match_parent instead of fill_parent. [Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use LinearLayout with its  layout_width="wrap_content" and its orientation="vertical". 
All the Buttons inside Layout, their layout_width should be "match_parent".
Its simple :)